# Defer loading of script with data attribute - Pinterest

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I have this code and I want to defer it to load after 10 seconds.

`<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>`

What I tried is :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: callback,
            async: true
        });
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.loadScript("https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js", function(){
            // Do nothing for now
        });
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

with different variants to include the data-pin-hover="true" part but without any help.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Done with jquery and plain js in the end:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        (function(d,s,id){
            var js,fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.setAttribute("data-pin-hover", true);
            js.src="https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
            }(document, "script", "pinterest-x3f")
        );
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it with ajax method of jQuery, instead of it you can create an element and add your attributes to it.

In your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function loadScript(src, attributes) {
            // creates a <script> tag and append it to the page
            // this causes the script with given src to start loading and run when complete
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            for(const element in attributes) {
                script.setAttribute(element, attributes[element]);
            }
            console.log(script)
            document.body.append(script);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            let attributes = {
                    'data-pin-hover' : true,
                    defer: '',
                    async: '',
                }

            loadScript("https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js", attributes, function(){
                // nothing
            });
        }, 10000);
    });
```